# Problems with implementing separate controller for each md-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

My template HTML file 'testview.html' looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <md-toolbar>
        <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span>Test View</span>
        </h2>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs
             md-selected="selectedIndex">
        <md-tab label="basicConfig">
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="awardSettings">
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>

    <div id="content" ui-view flex> </div>
</div>
```

This is my route controller 'testview.js':

```
angular
.module('app.testview')
.controller('TestView', TestView)
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('basicConfig', {
        url: '/basicConfig',
        templateUrl: 'app/testview/testview_partials/basicConfig.html',
        controller: 'BasicConfig as vm'
    })
    .state('awardSettings', {
        url: '/awardSettings',
        templateUrl: 'app/testview/testview_partials/awardSettings.html',
        controller: 'AwardSettings as vm'
    })
}]);

TestView.$inject = ['$state', '$scope', '$location'];

function TestView(state, $scope, $location) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = -1;

    $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(current, old) {
        switch (current) {
            case 0:
                $location.url("/basicConfig");
                break;
           case 1:
                $location.url("/awardSettings");
                break;
        }
    });

}
```

Here's what my awardSettings.html looks like:

```
<form name="awardSettingsForm" id="awardSettingsForm">
    <md-content flex layout-padding layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align-sm="space-between start" layout-align="space-between center">
        <label style="font-size: 24px;">Award Settings</label>
    </md-content>
</form>
```

I have my basicConfig & awardSettings html & controllers defined in separate files. I know that my routes are working correctly. But my problem is that I want the contents of basicConfig.html & awardSettings.html within their tabs. But that's not working. IT looks like below when I click on the tab
[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Could you put your code in a pluker?

Comment: @Mathews: No, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @troig . I am new to plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/uS4YCZ9ytqDgBO6BgU1S?p=preview

This is the code that I uploaded to plunker. But for some reason, the md-tabs are not showing up when running on plunker. Don't know if I need to add some other library also to the code.This same code works on my machine

Comment: Check the console in your browser for errors, you have mixed imports and are missing angular-aria and some other requirements. You also have 2x angular included.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZtOXa6Ieqi7zuo781zWD?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I figured out what I was doing wrong. Had to change sub states to be part of the main state ie. change state from 'basicConfig' to 'testview.basicConfig'.

```
function stateConfig ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('testview.basicConfig', {
    templateURL: 'app/testview/testview_partials/basicConfig.html',
    controller: 'BasicConfig'
  })
  .state('testview.awardSettings', {
    template: '<h3>Award!!</h3>',
    controller: 'AwardSettings'
  })
```

}